# I'm having trouble installing the Camera Perspective-n-Point add-on for Blender

Tags: blender, camera-calibration

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to make use of the Camera Perspective-n-Point plugin. The issue is that I have installed the plugin but the SOLVE PNP section, which is the one that makes the corrections to the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the camera, does not appear. Has anyone had something similar happen to them? The thing is that all the options that I see in the tutorials appear, except that one. Thanks for your help. Greetings

I would like to know if anyone else has had a similar experience and how they solved it.